# Присваивание указателю (char*), указатель на массива char

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, char

С указателями работаю не первый день, но с таким столкнулся первый раз.

Пример код:

```
    void fun(char *st){
        printf("data %s\n", st); // та же часть строки с мусором
    }

    void main(){

       char *key = header_to_tokens();
       char *handshake_head_p = NULL;
       int key_len = strlen(key);
       int handshake_key_len = (sizeof(char)) * (key_len + GUID_len);

       int header_total_len = 0;
       char handshake_key[handshake_key_len];

       if (strcpy(handshake_key, key) == NULL) {
          free(key);
          exit_error();
       }

       char *key_b64 = b64_encode(handshake_key, 20);

       if(key_b64 != NULL){ 
        int handshake_head_len = strlen(HANDSHAKE_HEAD);
        header_total_len = strlen(key_b64) + handshake_head_len + 4; // 129 символов.
        char handshake_head[header_total_len];
        memset(handshake_head, '\0', header_total_len);
        strcpy(handshake_head, HANDSHAKE_HEAD);
        strcat(handshake_head, key);

        printf("data %s\n", handshake_head); // все выводится как и задумывалось

        handshake_head_p = handshake_head;
       } else {
         er_exit();
       }

       printf("data %s\n", handshake_head_p);
       /*
        * только часть сообщения, где то 40 символов. Остальное мусор.
        * Если пропустить через strlen выдает 129.
        */

       fun(handshake_head_p);

       return 0;
    }
```

Где может быть ошибка? Это тот случай где нужно использовать char **? Суть задачи передать указатель массива, но обязательно с переприсвоением.

Comment: подоздреваю, что там мало места под строку, но мне сложно в уме считать все части. Добавляйте к параметрам компиляции  `-fsanitize=address` или запускайте с под valgrind. И ошибка вылезет.

Comment: Наверное не буду больше голову себе ломать и других подбивать на это дело.  Сделаю динамически.

Comment: @KoVadim работа с не gcc приучила что такие рассширениея желательно не использовать. Теоретически все вроде правильно но не работает

Comment: VLA это грубо говоря alloca, которая выделяет память на стеке. Если много не просить (по умолчанию до мегабайта), то ничего плохого не случится.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69670/discussion-on-question-by-----char-).

Answer (score 4):

Первое, что нужно понять, это то, как работает [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) - на стеке выделяется нужное кол-во байт (длина на размер элемента). Это выделение очень быстрое - просто нужно один регистр увеличить (а иногда оптимизатор может и это выбросить).

Второе, что нужно вспомнить, это время жизни переменных. Обычно на это натыкаются в с++, а в си компилятор достаточно умный, чтобы присекать использование переменной (например, просто `int i`, когда вышли за пределы блока (то есть, за соответствующий `}`). И VLA это один с тех случаев, когда нужно следить - вышел за пределы блока - указатель в мусор.

В измененном примере кода как раз и наблюдается эта ситуация - `handshake_head` создается в блоке, указатель на этот участок памяти (а он на стеке!) копируется в `handshake_head_p`, а потом происходит выход, стек подчищается и указатель уже указывает на память, которая уже не должна использоваться.

Но подобную ситуацию легко получить и без VLA. Вот схематический пример

```
int * p_i;
{
  int i = 2;
  p_i = &i;
}
foo(p_i);
```

**Что делать?**

Как всегда, внимательно следить за памятью. Самое простое, что я вижу - для handshake_head_p выделить память динамически и скопировать ее туда. Либо, как в комментариях предлагали, совсем отказаться от VLA.

А может, переписать логику программы так, что бы эта проблема не возникала.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял в чем моя ошибка. Исправлю с учётом Вашего ответа. You are master.